# If the user input is null or invalid, how can I make the code not do the next step

Tags: android, validation, if-statement

I have a data form and when the submit button is clicked, I'm checking if the user input in `EditText` is null or invalid. I want to make my code not go to confirmation window until the user input is not null and valid. How can I do this?

```
private void ifEmpty(EditText et, String message) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(et.getText())) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message + "を入力してください。",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
}

private void ifEmptyAndNum(EditText et, String message) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(et.getText())) {
        digitsOnly(et);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "数字を入力してください。", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message + "を入力してください。", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return;
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ifEmpty(etName, "Name");
    ifEmptyAndNum(etAge, "Age");
    ifEmpty(etAddress, "Address");
    ifEmptyAndNum(etTel, "Phone Number");

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra("name", etName.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("age", etAge.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("address", etAddress.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("tel", etTel.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I meant null as in no input, invalid is when the user input are not numbers in Age and Phone number.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [`if`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html), like this:

```
if (something) {
    // something was true
} else {
    // something was false
}
```

In your case, you have to adapt your validation methods, like this:

```
private boolean isEmpty(EditText et, String message) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(et.getText())) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message + "を入力してください。", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and use them like this:

```
if (isEmpty(etName, "Name")) {
    return; 
}
// ... (other fields validation)

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to prevent `startActivity(intent)` from happening if the input is invalid?

You can make your validation methods return a `boolean` and then halt execution if the input is invalid like this:

```
private boolean validateText(String text, String fieldName) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fieldName + " may not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


private boolean validateDigits(String text, String fieldName) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text) || !digitsOnly(text)) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fieldName + " may not be empty and must contain only digits", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    boolean everythingIsValid = validate(etName.getText(), "Name")
        || validateDigits(etAge.getText(), "Age")
        || validate(etAddress.getText(), "Address")
        || validateDigits(etTel.getText(), "Phone Number");

    if(!everythingIsValid) {
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra("name", etName.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("age", etAge.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("address", etAddress.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("tel", etTel.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```